# Can I force the TypeScript compiler to use nominal typing?

Tags: typescript, duck-typing

TypeScript uses [structural subtyping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html), so this is actually possible:

```
// there is a class
class MyClassTest {
    foo():void{}
    bar():void{}
}

// and a function which accepts instances of that class as a parameter
function someFunction(f:MyClassTest):void{
    if (f){
        if (!(f instanceof MyClassTest)) {
            console.log("why")
        } 
    }
}

// but it's valid to pass objects, which aren't in fact instances
// they just need to "look" the same, be "structural subtypes"
someFunction({foo(){}, bar(){}})  //valid!
```

However as the implementation provider of `someFunction` I would like to really forbid the passing of structurally similar objects, but I really only want to allow real instances of MyClassTest or its subtypes. I want to enforce "nominal typing" at least for some of my own function declarations.

Is this possible?

Background: Consider a case where the objects passed to the API need to be of that type, e.g. because they were produced by a factory which sets some internal state on this object and the object actually has a private interface that `someFunction` expects to be there in order to work properly. However I don't want to reveal that private interface (e.g. in a typescript definition file), but I want it to be a compiler error if someone passes in a fake implementation. Concrete example: I would like the typescript compiler to complain in this case, even if I provide all the members like so:

```
//OK for typescript, breaks at runtime
window.document.body.appendChild({nodeName:"div", namespaceURI:null, ...document.body})
```

Comment: There is a name for this, now: These types are called "branded types" - and there is even a special [`unique`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/symbols.html#unique-symbol) keyword that helps with the creation of [branded types](https://itnext.io/typing-basic-types-with-typescript-84288aa38b7c).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no compiler flag to make the compiler behave in a nominal way, indeed there in principle can't be such a flag as that would break a lot of javascript scenarios.

There are several techniques generally used to emulate some kind of nominal typing. Branded types are usually used for primitives (pick one from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A125734+branded+types) as a sample), for classes a common way is to add a private field (a private field will not structurally be matched by anything except that exact private field definition).

Using the last approach your initial sample could be written as:

```
// there is a class
class MyClassTest {
    private _useNominal: undefined; // private field to ensure nothing else is structually compatible.
    foo():void{}
    bar():void{}
}

// and a function which accepts instances of that class as a parameter
function someFunction(f:MyClassTest):void{
    if (f){
        if (!(f instanceof MyClassTest)) {
            console.log("why")
        } 
    }
}


someFunction({foo(){}, bar(){}, _useNominal: undefined})  //err
```

For your specific scenario, of using `append` I don't think we can do anything we can do since `Node` is defined in `lib.d.ts` as an interface and a `const`, so augmenting it with a private field is next to impossible (without changes to `lib.d.ts`), and even if we could it can potentially break a lot of existing code and definitions.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't actually looking for a global compiler flag. It's clear that such a flag could break a lot of code. I was hoping to be able to add some kind of modifier to the parameter type (like `someFunction(f:MyClassTest!)`) to change the behavior just for that method. The "private" hack is cool - but I guess it would not work in a type definition file, where private definitions make little sense.

Comment: @Sebastian you can use private fields in declarations  there is no issue with that since TS need to know about privates to prevent accidental overriding.  But in this case there just isn't a way to augment the existing definitions.

Comment: Actually a global (opt-in) flag like the `strictNullChecks` => `nominalTypeChecks` would be feasible, I guess - I don't believe it would break more code than `strictNullCheck` did. `interfaces` would still be duck-typed, anyway. I don't think that these fake-_class_es are used so frequently.