# Typescript InstanceType<T> is not behaving as I would imagine

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have following code:

```
class Factory<K, T extends new (...p: any) => any> {
    add(key: K, fn: (...p: ConstructorParameters<T>) => InstanceType<T>) {
    }
}

class Foo {
    constructor(a: number) {
    }
}

class Boo {
    constructor(a: number) {
    }
}

new Factory<number, typeof Foo>().add(1, (a) => new Boo(a))
```

I would assume that this should fail to compile as `Boo` is not derived from `Foo`. But it works fine.

Am I missing something?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBibAC4HsBOBPAPAaQDTQBVoBTAD0WIDsATGS4gd2gAoA6dgBwC5oxL0AlNAC8APl79xAbwBQ0eb2rVmAa2LoeeaADNKPNpx4BhZJQiJUAVyRoACmFRgAtsQqoImAqKFjoASTNEPmBiAnQOYk9vaFkFaABfGUSZUEgYWGRkGLkFYFNzKxtUZjAeSksnACNiVCFYhUTk1KhoACFM7Li8wMKUYtLocqqaupz5RpkZeiZ4Iqwh6tR8RHDiZG04TNFmAVYwJWYARnwSn3FptszTgSA)

Comment: TypeScript is a structurally typed language, if two objects have the same shape, they are considered to be of the same type. If you add something to `Foo` that `Boo` doesn't have, it'll stop compiling.

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova is correct. Here's the official explanation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-oop.html#rethinking-types. but if you *need* nominal types, there are some tricks: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/nominaltyping, https://michalzalecki.com/nominal-typing-in-typescript/, https://betterprogramming.pub/nominal-typescript-eee36e9432d2

Comment: Also, there is talk about introducing some kind of native support for nominal types: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/202 and https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33038

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55281684/11407695

Comment: It's helpful to read `extends` as "is assignable to", so your generic type parameter just needs to "be assignable to" `typeof Foo`, which `Boo` is (thanks to structural typing, as @NadiaChibrikova said).