# Why doesn't the following TypeScript program throw a type error?

Tags: typescript, generics, interface, typeerror, type-safety

Consider the [following program](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-VG0FHCBO5CW1025B2k3eC0h90qohAA).

```js
interface Eq<A> {
  eq(this: A, that: A): boolean;
};

class Pair<A> implements Eq<Pair<A>> {
  constructor(public x: A, public y: A) {}

  eq(this: Pair<A>, that: Pair<A>): boolean {
    return this.x === that.x && this.y === that.y;
  }
}

class Triple<A> implements Eq<Triple<A>> {
  constructor(public x: A, public y: A, public z: A) {}

  eq(this: Triple<A>, that: Triple<A>): boolean {
    return this.x === that.x && this.y === that.y && this.z === that.z;
  }
}

const eq = <A extends Eq<A>>(x: A, y: A): boolean => x.eq(y);

console.log(eq(new Pair(1, 2), new Triple(1, 2, 3)));
console.log(eq(new Triple(1, 2, 3), new Pair(1, 2)));
```

I would have expected the TypeScript compiler to complain about the last two lines, because you shouldn't be able to apply the `eq` function to two values of different types. However, the TypeScript compiler doesn't throw any type error for the above program. The result of the above program is `true` and `false`.

Why doesn't the TypeScript compiler throw a type error for the above program? How can we get it to correctly catch these kinds of type errors?

Comment: Hmm, for a moment I thought it was [Why are function parameters bivariant?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-function-parameters-bivariant) but I think there was another limitation you've hit. IIRC, it's when you try to have generic type parameter which is also generic. I'll try to find it but my memory of the exact problem is a but fuzzy. Perhaps somebody else will come in with links to a TS bug and more information.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is [Allow classes to be parametric in other parametric classes](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213)  which is a feature request for higher kinded types in TS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program compiles due to [structural subtyping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) used in TypeScript (as opposed to nominal subtyping often present in other programming languages).

Note that your `Triple` class is a can be assigned to a variable of type `Pair`:

```ts
const p: Pair<number> = new Triple(1, 2, 3);
```

In your example:

```ts
console.log(eq(new Pair(1, 2), new Triple(1, 2, 3)));
console.log(eq(new Triple(1, 2, 3), new Pair(1, 2)));
```

The type of `eq` is inferred to be:

```ts
const eq: <Pair<number>>(x: Pair<number>, y: Pair<number>) => boolean
```

As shown above, `Triple` is a valid argument for a parameter of type `Pair`, so everything compiles cleanly.

You could add a different private field to your classes to simulate nominal subtyping. In this particular example, you could pick between one of two options:

- add additional marker field
- make `x`, `y`, `z` private and provide getters

See [Can I force the TypeScript compiler to use nominal typing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55281162/can-i-force-the-typescript-compiler-to-use-nominal-typing)

Comment: All right, but then why does the second example also not throw an error? You can't assign a pair to a triple.

Comment: There is no place where `Pair` to `Triple` assignment is attempted - the type of `A` in `eq` is inferred to `Pair<number>` in both cases.

Comment: That's weird. Why is the type assumed to be `Pair<number>` instead of `Triple<number>` in the second case? It's clearly using the `Triple<number>` implementation of `eq` because the result is `false`. If it were using the `Pair<number>` implementation then the result would have been `true`.

Comment: 1. It infers `Pair<number>` because it is the most specific type shared by both arguments. 2. In runtime, when eq is executed `x.eq(y)` needs to be evaluated. Here, regular name lookup is applied: `eq` is looked up in `x` and up its prototype chain. If you pass `Pair` as a first argument, the definition of `eq` from `Pair` is used. Similarly, if you pass `Triple` as a first argument, `eq` from `Triple` is used. To reiterate: this is a dynamic, runtime lookup - not a static, compile time lookup.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I vote for @VLAZ 'es comments.

Since Pair and Triple both implementing `Eq`, I believe this is why you dont' have a compilation error.

Also, according @VLAZ'es comment, TS does not support higher kinded types.

SInce you are using F-bounded polymorphism, I believe you should give TS a hint about second argument.

```js
interface Eq<A> {
  eq(this: A, that: A): boolean;
};

class Pair<A> implements Eq<Pair<A>> {
  constructor(public x: A, public y: A) { }

  eq(this: Pair<A>, that: Pair<A>): boolean {
    return this.x === that.x && this.y === that.y;
  }
}

class Triple<A> implements Eq<Triple<A>> {
  constructor(public x: A, public y: A, public z: A) { }

  eq(this: Triple<A>, that: Triple<A>): boolean {
    return this.x === that.x && this.y === that.y && this.z === that.z;
  }
}

// hint is here :D
const eq = <Fst extends Eq<Fst>, Scd extends Eq<Scd> & Fst>(x: Fst, y: Scd): boolean => x.eq(y);

const x = eq(new Pair(1, 2), new Triple(1, 2, 3)); // ok
const y = eq(new Triple(1, 2, 3), new Pair(1, 2)); // error
```

This is not a full answer but I hope it gives you some clues