# Prevent Typescript to allow substitution with parent class?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typechecking

Why does this code works in Typescript? The specified type is `Child`, but it also allows any super-class (`Parent`) to be passed... It should only work the other way around (substituting a parent-class with a child one).

```
class Parent {
  constructor(private foo: string) {}

  bar() {
    return this.foo;
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  bar() {
    return 'baz';
  }
}

function doSomething(item: Child) {}

doSomething(new Parent('')); // No type error here...
```

Is there anyway to restrict this so that a type error is raised?

**EDIT** : simplified example

**EDIT 2** : filled classes with example content

Comment: Have you tried filling up your classes yet? https://tsplay.dev/mqYvQm

Comment: TypeScript uses a [structural type system](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system), so your `Parent` and `Child` classes are [assignable to each other's type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvuIZ.png). You can give the `Child` some exclusive structure to make it incompatible with `Parent` — example:  https://tsplay.dev/WoYllN

Comment: [Please don't use empty classes in example code; they behave strangely](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely).

Comment: I've tried with content, same thing. I'll edit the example for more clarity, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#starting-out

> The basic rule for TypeScript’s structural type system is that x is compatible with y if y has at least the same members as x. For example consider the following code involving an interface named Pet which has a name property:

```js
interface Pet {
  name: string;
}

let pet: Pet;
// dog's inferred type is { name: string; owner: string; }
let dog = { name: "Lassie", owner: "Rudd Weatherwax" };
pet = dog;
```

> To check whether dog can be assigned to pet, the compiler checks each property of pet to find a corresponding compatible property in dog. In this case, dog must have a member called name that is a string. It does, so the assignment is allowed.
>
> The same rule for assignment is used when checking function call arguments:

```js
interface Pet {
  name: string;
}

let dog = { name: "Lassie", owner: "Rudd Weatherwax" };

function greet(pet: Pet) {
  console.log("Hello, " + pet.name);
}
greet(dog); // OK
```

> Note that dog has an extra owner property, but this does not create an error. Only members of the target type (Pet in this case) are considered when checking for compatibility.
>
> This comparison process proceeds recursively, exploring the type of each member and sub-member.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by [@jsejcksn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75870548/prevent-typescript-to-allow-substitution-with-parent-class#comment-133827399), Typescript only looks for structural similarities for typing, and not the types themselve. This is also answered in more depths [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55281162/can-i-force-the-typescript-compiler-to-use-nominal-typing).