# Why is TypeScript not telling me about this LSP Violation?

Tags: typescript

I have an interface that exposes one method, and a class that implements that method (incorrectly). It is taking a more specific type as the interface and Typescript is not giving me any sort of compiler error, why? Is there something wrong with my tsconfig?

This violates the Liskov Substitution Principle and I believe that in C# or another type safe language this would throw an error.

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKAOBTYBLAZi4BGaBvAvgFCGiQwLLqYBMeRJ4U0ASogC4CuATgHYAqATyR1ipJgAlIAC1jsAPHwB80FAFt4IRKsQ82MAJJtEXMACNNC5bkIBtWANWmA9iAB0KIybZOuAXQAUAJQAXNCGxmDeXAoANGA8AjEcPAAmiBg8iClWhGxSXE4A7tCZxQCiXAVc-gBEALLsUk4pJU5sKuqa2rpZrjWBANyERPRsQojQAOI6ESDQALxwSKgY2NAAPkuUq9RDhIgAHvA+7Sg9XGhgwBOwTtoAYldRAniE0NAA9ABUX2-vX9A6mAANYTCDsGBONDQQooLiICAxaDAO7HTK6GDxFo8ZoI6DeP7QAGqJwANwm3gA5o1jNA0AVVNAwNBwZpgEYWuD2lCYXCEa5CV8Pn9VCDELI9P4PFoIKFwiZzIg5NNMiYQIoQtAAIKVMACOSsTi8QRIRRDeiHY5cdpich3RCPdk+AT6dQdDRaHR6OD2x3PV7veAccyYaCi0ESiD+Qm8+Gy6CSCAyeQUFaYLCKJEfD7QPhSFAwAthnxg5ZUYD4qTxMKeMwWFWzTOVouklAuSJ4vITAAysAACn9NTqTPrDdx+OMcu93nkCsVStAKlUgkN3iMgA)

```js
class Specific1 {}

class Specific2 {}

class ReturnType {}

class HashSet<T> implements Iterable<T> {
[Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<T,any,undefined> {
throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
}
}

type General = Specific1 | Specific2;

export interface SomeFactory {
  /**
   * Make sets of wires, components and nodes to
   * move together from a selected set of wires.
   */
  makeSets(items: Iterable<General>): Array<ReturnType>;
}

export class SomeFactoryImp implements SomeFactory {
  public makeSets(
    wires: HashSet<Specific1>, // This is more specific than Iterable<General>, this violates the LSP
  ): Array<ReturnType> {
    throw new Error();
  }
}
```

In this case Specific1 is more specific than General, and HashSet is more specific than Iterable, both of these should give me an error but my IDE is not saying anything.

I'm using a monorepo, so my tsconfig is kinda all over the place. To keep this simple please refer to the tsconfig in the Typescript Playground.

Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I force the TypeScript compiler to use nominal typing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55281162/can-i-force-the-typescript-compiler-to-use-nominal-typing)

Answer (score 3):

```
class Specific1 {}

class Specific2 {}

class ReturnType {}

type General = Specific1 | Specific2;
```

Typescript uses structural typing, not nominal typing. In other words, typescript compares types by looking at what properties they contain, not what their name or origin is. As a result, all 4 of these are the same type: they all describe objects which have no required properties.

```
makeSets(items: Iterable<General>): Array<ReturnType>
// ...
makeSets(wires: HashSet<Specific1>): Array<ReturnType>
```

Similarly, here typescript will compare these by their structure. `Iterable<General>` means an object with a `[Symbol.iterator]` property, and that property contains an iterator that spits out objects with no required properties. `HashSet<Specific1>` means the same thing: an object with a `[Symbol.iterator]` property, and that property contains an iterator that spits out objects with no required properties.

In a structural type system these are the same type, and thus compatible.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html

---

P.S: While i think your specific question is just a misunderstanding of structural vs nominal types, it **is** possible to write typescript code which is unsound. In fact, typescript explicitly does *not* have a goal to be provably correct. That's one of the tradeoffs that comes with bolting a type system on to an existing language (javascript) that didn't have types.

> Non-Goals
> // ...
> 3. Apply a sound or "provably correct" type system. Instead, strike a balance between correctness and productivity.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals

Answer (score 0):

You are speaking about other language such as C#: I know that in Java this would fail to compile because you are not overriding the method, but instead providing an overload.

You would use `@Override` on implementation to tell Java this method is overriding one from its parent type: Java would then fail if the signature did not match (ignoring the return type, eg: an implementation may return a subtype of the parent' return).

In TypeScript, you also have an `override` but it does not seems to work with `interface` (strangely enough, the `@Override` in Java was extended in Java 6 to also work with interface):

```
public override makeSets(
    wires: HashSet<Specific1>, // This is more specific than Iterable<General>, this violates the LSP
  ): Array<ReturnType>
```

This produce an error because `SomeFactory` is an interface.

I think your problem (which is the same as mine) is that interface in TypeScript are not the same as interface in Java or C#: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces

> Just like when we used a type alias above, the example works just as if we had used an anonymous object type. TypeScript is only concerned with the structure of the value we passed to printCoord - **it only cares that it has the expected properties**. Being concerned only with the structure and capabilities of types is why we call TypeScript a structurally typed type system.

When you implement an interface in TypeScript, it seems it does only care about it being present and returning a value: you can remove the parameters in `makeSets` and it still compile.